# Insert vertical slices into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, slice

In a recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664086/delete-an-array-column-and-change-position-of-two-columns/62666087#comment110846318_62666087) I demonstrated how to use *array arguments* in the **`Application.Index()`** function (instead of single indices)
to rearrange the current columns order in any direction (switch columns, omit/delete columns).

```
    Application.Index(data, {vertical rows array}, {horizontal columns array})
```

This approach doesn't need loops and allows to get any new column order defined just by listing the new column positions, in OP e.g. via

```
     Array(1, 4, 2)
```

in other words

- the 1st column,
- (the 3rd one omitted=deleted),
- the remaining columns 4 and 2 in switched order*:

```
Sub DeleteAndSwitch()
'[1]get data
    Dim data: data = Sheet1.Range("A1:D4")
'[2]reorder columns via Array(1, 4, 2), i.e. get 1st column, 4th and 2nd column omitting the 3rd one
'   (evaluation gets all existing rows as vertical 2-dim array)
    data = Application.Index(data, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) & ")"), Array(1, 4, 2))
'[3]write to any target
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

A related comment asked:

> *"I can **slice** a 2D array, I can **eliminate** column, **reorder** columns, but I cannot ►**insert** a column(s) slice in such an array...
> In fact, I can do it using iteration, but did you find a similar way to insert such a vertical slice?"*

**Methodical hints**

As is at least frequently known, a given column (e.g. the 4th) can be sliced from an array (here e.g. `data`) via

```
    Column4Data = Application.Index(data, 0, 4)
```

resulting itself in a 1-based 2-dim "vertical" array.

It's **not** possible, however to assign a vertical slice to another one; the following code would raise a 1004  error (Application-defined or object-defined error):

```
Application.Index(data, 0, 4) = Application.Index(data, 0, 1)
```

**Question**

> Is there *any* possibility to insert a column(s) slice in an array (without iteration)?

There does exist  a possibility to arrange such column data in a temporary array of arrays (*"jagged array"*) and to build a 2-dim array from this base.

In order not to *overcharge* this post I'll demonstrate this rather unknown approach as ►separate answer looking forward to **any** other or better approach.

**Related link**
[Some pecularities of the `Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: Why not just paste your data to a worksheet, move it around on the sheet as desired, and then copy the range back to an array?

Comment: Appreciate your hint in comment: this post intended mainly to inform about 
further possibilities of `Application.Index()` as addition to a prior answer. - 
If the target is to insert only one column without further column order re-sortings, 
I'd prefer your approach when using Excel VBA without any doubt (see also preface to the Addition part). @johnywhy

Answer (score 2):

**Jagged array approach using `Application.Index()`**

For the sake of completeness I show this approach in order to demonstrate a further and widely unknown possibility of the `Application.Index()` function.

By  adding (transposed) slices to a temporary "Array of Arrays" first, it's possible to create a 2-dim array in a second step via **double zero** *arguments* using the following syntax (c.f. section **`[2]b`**):

```
    data = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(data, 0, 0))
```

```
Sub InsertSlices()
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'[0]define extra array (or slice AND transpose from other data source)
    Dim Extra: Extra = Array(100, 200, 300, 400)   ' example data
'[1]get data
    Dim data: data = Tabelle7.Range("A1:D4")
'[2]a) rewrite data as 1-dim array of sliced column arrays
    data = Array(Extra, Slice(data, 1), Slice(data, 4), Slice(data, 2))
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'[2]b) rebuild as 2-dim array
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    data = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(data, 0, 0))
'[3]write to any target
    Tabelle7.Range("F1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

```
Function Slice(DataArr, ByVal colNo As Long) As Variant()
'Purpose: return entire column data as 2-dim array and
'         transpose them here to get a "flat" 1-dim array of column data
With Application
    Slice = .Transpose(.Index(DataArr, 0, colNo))
End With
End Function
```

**Caveat:** *The repeated transformation of data in two steps can be time consuming for larger data sets.*

---

**Workaround**

Therefore I'd prefer the basic approach in the cited post via ►*array arguments* in the `Application.Index()` function, but by inserting a (e.g. temporary) column to the physical data range *first* and eventually by rearranging the columns including the newly added extra data (last position) at any new position (e.g. here on top).

```
Sub DelSwitchAndInsert()
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'[0]add other array data as last column to existing range
    Sheet1.Range("E1:E4") = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
'[1]get data
    Dim data: data = Tabelle7.Range("A1:E4")
'[2]reorder via Array(1, 4, 2), i.e. get 1st column, 4th and 2nd column omitting the 3rd one
    data = Application.Index(data, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) & ")"), Array(UBound(data, 2), 1, 4, 2))
'[3]write to any target
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

**Addendum to workaround in response to recent comments** *//Edit/2020-07-07*

A flexible example following the workaround logic for insertion of vertical extra single-column data at any given "column" number could be as follows; I don't pretend this to be neither the best method nor the best way to code:

```
    InsCol data, extra, 3        ' insertion e.g. as new 3rd "column"
```

```
Sub InsertExtraData()
'Purpose:  insert a single-column array (2-dim, 1-based)
    '[0]define extra array (or slice AND transpose from other data source)
        Dim extra: extra = Application.Transpose(Array(100, 200, 300, 400))   ' example data
    '[1]get data (or existing 2-dim array)
        Dim data: data = Sheet1.Range("A1:D4")
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[2]insert extra as >>3rd<< column
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        InsCol data, extra, 3
    '[3]write to any target
        Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

```
Sub InsCol(data, extra, Optional ByVal colNo As Long = 1)
With Sheets.Add
    '[0]add data to temporary range
    .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
    .Range("B1").Offset(0, UBound(data, 2)).Resize(UBound(extra) - LBound(extra) + 1, 1) = extra
    '[1]get data
        data = .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2) + 1)
    '[2]reorder via Array(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
        data = Application.Index(data, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) & ")"), getColNums(data, colNo))
    '[3]delete temporary sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False: .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
End Sub
```

```
Function getColNums(main, Optional ByVal colNo As Long = 1) As Variant()
    'c.f. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727578/joining-two-arrays-in-vba/60082345#60082345
    'Purp.: return ordinal element counters of combined 0-based 1-dim arrays
    Dim i&, n&: n = UBound(main) + 1    ' +1 as one column, +1 from 0-based~>one-based
    ReDim tmp(0 To n - 1)               ' redim to augmented size (zero-based)
    If colNo > n Then colNo = n
    If colNo < 1 Then colNo = 1
    For i = 0 To colNo - 1: tmp(i) = i + 1: Next i
    tmp(colNo - 1) = n
    For i = colNo To UBound(tmp): tmp(i) = i: Next i
    getColNums = tmp        ' return combined elem counters,  e.g. Array(1,2, >>5<< ,3,4)
End Function
```

Comment: Very nice! Voted it Up. `Insert slices` works like a charm, solving my "dilema". I am trying to transform `DelSwitchAndInsert` in a way to **only** insert another column (the Extra one of the previous Sub), without any reordering, but I do not get it....

Comment: Does this help? - The basic idea of the workaround is to `[0]` *add/append* the extra data as new column right to an existing range or
to fill a temporary or hidden target range with any existing array plus the most right extra data , `[1]` include the new "last" column into the extended array assignment and
`[2]` insert the most right column number `Array(UBound(data, 2)` to any wished position in the current columns array argument `Array(1,2,3,4)` ~> e.g. `Array(UBound(data,2), 1, 2, 3, 4)` for a final rearrangement as new first column.

Comment: It helped, of course! But my (declared) interest is connected to inserting of **a new built column** between the existing ones. As `Insert slices` does. If I am not missing anything, the second one only switches or inserts **existing columns**. I could not adapt it to accept a new created (column) array on the mecanism of the previous `Sub`. I mean, inserting of `Extra` array... But this does not mean that everything presented is not extremely interesting... :) I like using arrays and until now I couldn't  insert a column in a compact way.

Comment: If I will also succed to adapt the second one to insert a column from outside, I will declare myself extremely satisfied, too! :)

Comment: I appreciate your interest. - I am not quite sure, however to understand you correcty: the result is the same, it inserts extra data at any wanted column position, but with the additional step via a temporary range reassigning the combined data A:D plus an added temporary E column to the right (moved only thereafter via `Application.Index). Because of this additional step I consider this working (btw faster) approach as workaround to the original question. *I'd have liked to find an abbreviated way here, too* :-) @FaneDuru

Comment: Edited a flexibilized example following the workaround logic (`InsCol data, extra, 3` inserts e.g. a 3rd column), hopefully helpful :-) @FaneDuru